# Play the transparent video on top of UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, video, transparent, alpha

I want to play the transparent video on top of UIView. Can it be possible?
There are few resources on this like AVAnimator and GPUIMage. But I want to develop this with native iOS libraries. I don't want to use any 3rd party library. So please help me on this regard.
What approach should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

You should use SpriteKit, it's a native library and very easy to use.

You can do some truly amazing stuff with minimal code.

You can play a video over a UIView transparently and even add physics and weight to it!

Documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH1-SW1

In the WWDC Developer videos from 2013, there is a demo showing exactly what you want to do, so check them out,

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

It's called Designing Games with Sprite Kit (all you care about is the Video type sprite, SKVideoNode)

Comment: Thanks John for your response. It is useful. I hope I could make my application for >= iOS 7. :)

Comment: No problem whatsoever, if your question is answered by this please mark it as answered, if not no problem :) Glad to help.

Comment: John, how would SprikeKit be able to play a video with an alpha channel when this is not support by iOS? Is this some new video format that has been adding in iOS 7? As far as the docs go, they just say that a video node uses the standard AVPlayer interface and this interface does not support an alpha channel.

Comment: SKNode superclass has an alpha property, independent to the video content.

Comment: An alpha channel in the video is not the same thing as rendering video content into a window and then setting the alpha for the whole window. An alpha channel is an alpha value on a pixel by pixel basis defined in the video.